# Doubt in the proof of Krull's principal ideal theorem

Tags: commutative-algebra

Krull's principal ideal theorem states that

$A$ *is a Noetherian ring and (x) is a principal, proper ideal of $A$, then each minimal prime ideal over (x) has height at most one.*

According to proof which is available on Wikipedia, it starts in the  following way-

> Let $A$ be Noetherian ring, *x* be an element of it and $\mathfrak p$ be minimal prime over *x*.  Replacing $A$ by localization $A_{\mathfrak p}$.We can assume that $A$ is local with maximal ideal $\mathfrak p$.....

Now, I know that $A_{\mathfrak p}$ is local with maximal as well as prime ideal $\mathfrak pA_{\mathfrak p}$. But  I'm not able to understand the part in the proof where it says *we can  assume  that $A$ is local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak p$*.

Can someone please tell me how we can assume that $A$ is local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak p$?

Comment: Nothing has changed by localization: $pA_p$ remain s minimal over $x$ and its height equals the height of $p$.

Comment: @user26857 So basically we are proving the theorem for local ring $A_\mathfrak p$ with prime ideal $\mathfrak pA_\mathfrak p$?

Comment: Right.${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if $R$ is a ring and $U$ is a multiplicative set in $R$, then the prime ideals of the localization $U^{-1}R$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the prime ideals of $R$ which do not intersect $U$.

To be more precise, if
$$T = \{\mathfrak{q} \in \text{Spec}(R): \mathfrak{q} \cap U = \emptyset \}$$
Then $$\text{Spec}(U^{-1}R) = \{U^{-1}\mathfrak{q}:\mathfrak{q}\in T \}$$
In particular, if $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal of $R$, then the prime ideals of $R_{\mathfrak{p}}$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the prime ideals of $R$ which are contained in $\mathfrak{p}$.

Therefore, the height of $\mathfrak{p}$ in $R$ is equal to the height of $\mathfrak{p}R_{\mathfrak{p}}$ in the localized ring $R_{\mathfrak{p}}$. So, showing that $\text{ht}(\mathfrak{p})\le 1$ is equivalent to showing that $\text{ht}(\mathfrak{p}R_{\mathfrak{p}})\le 1$.